# Xcode commit window -- show unix-diff-like diff (don't show the whole file)

Tags: xcode, macos, diff, commit

Talking about latest Xcode (4.2.1) on latest Mac OS X Lion (10.7.3).

When you press <kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, Xcode pulls up a window showing the new file and the old revision of the file side-by-side.

I like the elegance of the interface; however, sometimes it's not ideal for longer files.

The problem is, Xcode shows you the ENTIRE file, so in order to see all the changes, you basically have to scroll through the whole file. This is especially annoying if you just made a change consisting of a few lines -- you still have to scroll through the whole file to check you accidentally aren't commiting something else.

Is there a way to make Xcode behave like the UNIX `diff`, which shows you ONLY the changed portions of the files (plus a few lines of context)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not exactly what I was looking for, but it helps nevertheless:

I found out you can click on the region between the two files, and then use up/down arrow keys to directly move between regions which have changed.

This simplifies viewing the diffs greatly.